# How to get permissions by name for each role a liferay user has

Tags: java, liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet

I've been working on access control.So,In our liferay portlets,how can I get all permissions of a user,I've achieved getting roles of a user by

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) facesContext
            .getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
User user = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);  
List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

roles.addAll(RoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserRoles(user.getUserId()));

roles.addAll(RoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserRelatedRoles(user.getUserId(), user.getGroupIds()));
```

But I cant find any thing by which I can find if the given user has view/configuration/etc permissions with respect to the portlets.`getResourceResourcePermissions` gives me the permission but by ids,How can I find permissions with permission name i.e view/config/update

`liferay 6.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if user has that permission one by one in the portlet.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay= (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
PortletDisplay portletDisplay = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay();
PermissionChecker permissionChecker = themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker();

long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
String name = (String)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
String primKey = portletDisplay.getResourcePK();
boolean view = permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primKey, ActionKeys.VIEW);
boolean congiguration = permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primKey, ActionKeys.CONFIGURATION);
boolean update = permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primKey, ActionKeys.UPDATE);
```

Comment: yep - you definitely want to use permissionChecker for this purpose and not care which way you get the permissions - e.g. through a regular role, site role, organization role or team. It's sufficient to know that a user is allowed an operation. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use this class PermissionFinderUtil. This class contains a lot of functions to get Permission.